# Saving two models with foreign key

Tags: magento

I'm curious whether this is even possible.

Basically I have two related models.  I'm wondering if it's possible to save both models as a transaction, automatically populating the foreign key of the second model with the new insert id of the first.

I know that this can be done by saving the models separately, but my question is whether it can be done as one save.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this by using after/before saves and modifying the data.  I passed the id around using the registry.

---

**My Solution**

```
//after first model save
public function _afterSave(){
    Mage::unregister('id');
    Mage::register('id', $this->getData('id'));
}

//before second model save
public function _beforeSave(){
    if (Mage::registry('id') && !$this->getData('id')) {
        $this->setData('id', Mage::registry('id'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It will be useful, I'm trying to do the same